# Inserting custom template before price on category page with XML - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, xml

I want to include a phtml file after the product title on a category page. See here:

[image]

In `app/design/vendor/theme/Magento_catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml` I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.block" template="Magento_Catalog::my-custom-template.phtml" before="product.info.price" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

and I have `my-custom-template.phtml` in `app/design/vendor/theme/Magento_catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`

but this outputs my file at the bottom of the page after all the products.

Can anyone help me reference the right place please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The products on the category pages aren't constructed with xml, so getting placement on this is not possible with xml alone. The products are set up here:

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml

So you can override this file in your theme and place the call to your custom template with this code:

```
<strong class="product name product-item-name">
    <a class="product-item-link"
       href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'); ?>
    </a>
</strong>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("Magento_Catalog::my-custom-template.phtml")->toHtml();?>
```

Comment: I feared that that would be the answer. Obviously I'm trying not to override any templates in the build but in this case it looks like I need to :( Thank you for your help.